# SQL - Using a Trigger to occasionally allow row deletions

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-delete

I have some views I'm working with, and I need to set up a trigger to prevent the deletion of any data within the view if the data table is locked by a variable in another table. I already have the trigger set up, and have no issue with setting up the replacement of the delete command using an 'INSTEAD OF DELETE' trigger, but my issue now is how to preserve the incoming delete query for the times where deletions *are* allowed. In this case, I'm using SQL Server.

For example, if the control table says my view is locked, then any delete query sent to the database should be stopped, and an error message should be returned (no problems here, have this already). However, if the control table says my view is unlocked, I need to be able to allow the delete query to delete data from the view (here I need help).

Code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [database_name].[trigger_name]
ON [database_name].[view_name]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [database_name].[control_table_name]
                   WHERE Control_Item = 'view_name' AND Can_modify = 'N')
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT OFF
        --NEW DELETION STATEMENT GOES HERE, NEEDS TO BE DUPLICATE OF REPLACED DELETE QUERY--
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        RAISEERROR('Deletions are currently disabled!', 11, 1);
    END
END
```

I'm sure there's some stupid logic statement or something I'm missing but I'll appreciate all the help I can get. Thanks!

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I'm using sql-server, will update the main post. Thanks for the info.

Comment: You cannot delete data from the view - you need to delete it from the underlying tables directly

Comment: Right, but I can delete data through the view, right? I just tried it, and it looks like I can... Should I update the main post to clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot delete from the view directly - you need to delete from the underlying table(s).

So basically, you need to add one (or several) `DELETE` statements for your tables - and hopefully, you've included the primary keys from all the underlying tables into your view!

```
CREATE TRIGGER [database_name].[trigger_name]
ON [database_name].[view_name]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [database_name].[control_table_name]
                   WHERE Control_Item = 'view_name' AND Can_modify = 'N')
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT OFF

        DELETE FROM dbo.YourFirstTable
        WHERE PrimaryKeyColumn IN (SELECT FirstPrimaryKeyColumn FROM Deleted);

        -- if the view is built on top of several tables, you possibly need multiple DELETE statements here
        DELETE FROM dbo.YourSecondTable
        WHERE PrimaryKeyColumn IN (SELECT SecondPrimaryKeyColumn FROM Deleted);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        RAISEERROR('Deletions are currently disabled!', 11, 1);
    END
END
```

Comment: Ok, so just to clarify, will the Deleted table contain the values that would have been deleted had the original delete query gone through?

Comment: Ok, so whenever I try this I get an error saying 'Deleted.FirstPrimaryKeyColumn' could not be bound.

Comment: @AlpheausFeltham: yes, `Deleted` will contain **all rows** that are part of your view and that would have been deleted. And of course, you need to **adapt** my code to use **YOUR** column names! You didn't post the view/table structures, so I have no means of knowing what your column names are - it just refers to the **primary key column** of the first table - replace it with whatever that column is called

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a 'FOR DELETE' can do the trick, and do a rollback when the delete is not allowed.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [database_name].[trigger_name] 
ON [database_name].[view_name]
FOR DELETE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM [database_name].[control_table_name]
               WHERE Control_Item = 'view_name' AND Can_modify = 'N')
    BEGIN
        RAISEERROR('Deletions are currently disabled!', 11, 1) WITH NOWAIT
        ROLLBACK
    END

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

Comment: That was my original thought, but views only allow for 'INSTEAD OF'

Comment: That's a bugger :(